# How to install Angularjs Material demo examples in local computer?

Tags: angularjs, github, npm, offline, demo

How do I install AngularjS material online demo source package on local computer.
The AngularJS Material Docs are generated from dgeni documentation generator the source code is on github.,these are the links.
I just need to install **angularjs material doc on my Ubuntu for offline use**

***Online demo:***
material.angularjs.org

***Online demo SorceCode:***
github.com/angular/material/tree/v1.1.4

***Dgeni documentation generator:***
github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/README.md

Comment: Have you got any solution please tell me

Comment: similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502717/how-to-run-angularjs-material-documentation-locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502717/how-to-run-angularjs-material-documentation-locally)