# How to run angularjs material documentation locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, npm, angular-material

I have compiled the newest **angularjs material** and find out that links in the doc all point to absolute URL material.angularjs.org/.... **I want to be able to read the doc and demo content locally.**

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps (for Windows users):

- Install `git`, `Node v6.10.3`

  Git  `https://git-for-windows.github.io/`

  Node v6.10.3  `https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v6.10.3/`
- Install dependencies `npm`,`glub` and `http-server`(use cmd or
  PowerShell)

  npm Insatall  `npm install npm@3.10.10`

  gulp Insatall `npm install --global gulp-cli`

  http-server Insatall `npm install http-server -g`
- Clone the angular-material repository:

  `git clone https://github.com/angular/material.git`
- Build the repository:

  `cd material`
  `npm install`
- Build the docs:

  `gulp build;`
  `gulp docs;`
  `gulp watch --dev`
- run the docs:

  `cd dist/docs;`
  `http-server`

Then simply go to http://192.168.42.130:8080 or http://127.0.0.1:8080

*Special thanks for **Prerak Sola**

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repo : https://github.com/angular/material

and then launch with your webserver the docs dir that has all resources generated for the documentation.

There is even a README in the doc dir : https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the offline documentation by following the below steps:

- Install `git`, `nodejs` and `npm`
- Install `gulp`:
  `npm install --global gulp-cli`
- Clone the angular-material repository:
  `git clone https://github.com/angular/material.git`
- Build the repository:
  `cd material`
  `npm install`
- Build the docs:
  `gulp watch site --dev`

Currently the documentation building task is failing. I have submitted a issue [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10728). Follow this to see what workaround or update they provide.

**Update:**
As per the response [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10728#issuecomment-307935462), you'll need to install `node v6.10.3` and `npm 3.10.10` for building the docs locally. Install these specific versions and follow the above steps.